# select default for radio buttons inside a loop modelled with dynamic ngModel

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-ngmodel

I have a for loop containing inputs, each loop consists of five radio values whose name and model are dynamic.

I want to set value 1 as default, I can use the usual html "checked" or "checked = checked" but it works only without ngModel, if I'm using ngModel, I have to initialize it in the component class but since, it's dynamic there's no way I can initialize it first.

Is there any alternative or am I missing anything??

```
<div class="scorecard-attribute" *ngFor="let attribute of opportunity.scorecard.scorecard_attributes">
   <input type="radio" name="{{attribute.name}}" [value]=1 [(ngModel)]="newRating[attribute.id]" checked>
   <input type="radio" name="{{attribute.name}}" [value]=2 [(ngModel)]="newRating[attribute.id]">
   <input type="radio" name="{{attribute.name}}" [value]=3 [(ngModel)]="newRating[attribute.id]">
   <input type="radio" name="{{attribute.name}}" [value]=4 [(ngModel)]="newRating[attribute.id]">
   <input type="radio" name="{{attribute.name}}" [value]=5 [(ngModel)]="newRating[attribute.id]">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your HTML file,

```
<div class="scorecard-attribute" *ngFor="let attribute of opportunity.scorecard.scorecard_attributes">
   <input type="radio" [value]="attribute" [(ngModel)]="newRating" (click)="click(attribute)">{{attribute.name}}
</div>
```

Add this code in component file,

```
newRating:any=opportunity.scorecard.scorecard_attributes[0];

click(obj){
   console.log(obj);
}
```

Thanks,